# Most websites never load and can't ping them, on a wired connection

Tags: internet, 17.04

I am really new to Ubuntu. I have dual installation along with Windows 10. The Internet was working fine for quite some time. But later on it turned out that only a few websites are loading properly like facebook.com, google.com, youtube.com. But most of the websites are not loading. They just stay in a loading state. I have tried several solutions given in this website. Almost everything like adding `nameserver 8.8.8.8.` like so.  These websites are not getting pinged as well. The Internet is working fine in my Windows 10 installation.

The Internet is a Cable/wired connection.

Can somebody shed some light on this? What are the possible ways I can check?

**UPDATE:**
The ifconfig output:

```
$ ifconfig
.enp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 1c:1b:0d:24:a2:79  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 10823  bytes 10193851 (10.1 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 845  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 6312  bytes 782934 (782.9 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 2777  bytes 213323 (213.3 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2777  bytes 213323 (213.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

ppp0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 100.72.21.244  netmask 255.255.255.255  destination 1.186.179.1
        ppp  txqueuelen 3  (Point-to-Point Protocol)
        RX packets 9956  bytes 9921866 (9.9 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 6294  bytes 643846 (643.8 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Comment: It looks like you get only IPV6 address. It is a known bug when Ubuntu randomly gets only IPV6. It can be fixed by reconnecting in Network Manager. You can check if you get IPV4 in NM.

Comment: Post output of `ifconfig` to your question. You can click on "Disconnect" in NM, then click "Connect". NM is the network icon on top of the screen.

Comment: It looks like you are using PPPoE. The mtu is wrong. How did you setup PPPoE. If you did that in NM change it to 1492.

Comment: @Pilot6, I have configured it through Network Manager. DSL connection. I have tried adding mtu in the files interfaces/options files also. But no luck

Comment: Which `files interfaces/options`? Change it in NM the DSL connection.

Comment: I really appreciate your efforts. That seems to have been paid. I configured internet  through `pppoeconf`. And it seems to be loading most of the websites. Thanks very much for your support.

Comment: The only thing you needed was to change mtu, but it looks like you just didn't find the option. `pppoeconf` does that correctly by default.

Comment: Yes that would be correct. Bravo

Answer (score 1):

I tried to configure the Internet through `pppoeconf` and it all started working on. Thanks [Pilot6](https://askubuntu.com/users/167850/pilot6) for pointing me to the right direction.